# Push ObjectId in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

I'm using express, passport, and mongoose. I don't know why but the code below pushes same `newTaxReturn._id` twice into `user.taxReturnIds` field. If I remove `user.save().catch(() => {})` line, it pushes the `newTaxReturn._id` correctly i.e. just once. The user argument is from passport.

Problem:

```
const createTaxReturn = ({ user }) => {
  const newTaxReturn = new TaxReturn({ userId: user._id })
  user.taxReturnIds.push(newTaxReturn._id)
  user.save().catch(() => {})
  return newTaxReturn.save().catch(() => {})
}
```

Schema:

```
const User = new mongoose.Schema({
  taxReturnIds: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'TaxReturn',
  }],
})

const TaxReturn = new mongoose.Schema({
  userId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
  },
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your return you are also calling .save() thus the duplication and the single input when you remove

```
user.save().catch(() => {})
```

place your return in a .then or .catch to retrieve the response from mongo

```
user.save().catch(error => { if (error) return error })
```